# After I defined global settings for headers (h1, h2 ...) in CSS is there a way to add headline-specific settings?

Tags: html, css

I want to set some common global settings for e.g., the first 6 headline types in CSS, e.g,

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { 
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700; 
    color: #222;
    line-height:120%; 
}
```

However, I want to have different paddings for the different headlines, e.g.,

`padding-top:80px` for h1, `padding-top:60px` for h2 etc.

How would I best do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the general style you wrote above, simply add the more specific styles for each heading.

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    /* generic style for every header */
}

h1 {
    /* specific style for level 1 header */
}
```

Comment: Actually, it will. If you define on the generic selector a `padding-top` and then define this property again in a more specific selector, the latter will be considered instead (what's not your case, because the selector is the same,  `h1` at my example - in this case, it takes precedence because it appears after the first selector. For more info, see http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/ specially on  "Specificity: Basic Principles"

Answer (score 0):

You do it just like you said.

```
h1 {
    padding-top: 80px;
}

h2 {
    padding-top: 60px;
}

etc...
```